# TypeScript Conditional logic on a Promise<boolean> allows code execution when run synchronously

Tags: typescript, if-statement, asynchronous

I have a business logic library with a method that is designed to run asynchronously, passing false to be used in an if statement. If run asynchronously, it's fine:

```
const permissions = new PermissionProvider(userId,appId);

if(await permissions.ifAllowed('invalid action', itemID)){
     // This code is not reachable.
}

export class PermissionProvider {
...
public async ifAllowed(action: string, itemId?: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return await db.query(params)
    .then(() => { return false; }
}
```

However, I'm concerned someone may accidentally run the code synchronously:

```
if(permissions.ifAllowed('invalid action', itemID)){
     // This code executes because asynchronous functions return a Promise,
     // and objects evaluate to true.
}
```

Simply documenting that the API must be run with the async/await seems precarious. This is particularly bad because it may not be obvious that the end user will be allowed to do pretty much anything if the await keyword is omitted.

If I return a primitive boolean instead, the async code then returns undefined because it's coming from the database as a Promise.

**Is there a good workaround to either enforcing async calls on the consumer of the API, or preventing the if statement from evaluating true?**

I tried throwing an uncaught error, but it still executes the code because the error is thrown after the if statement is already executed.

Comment: Let me try to clarify this question a bit: you feel responsible for improper use of your library and want to prevent it, right?

Comment: That is correct. The code works with await, but only with await. Without it, the promise may resolve to false, but the conditional will resolve to true. Ideally, there would be some mechanism such as reflection or type checking that would prevent the method from being called without await.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid there is nothing you can enforce on your side, since any user can just disable all strict checks or linter warnings if that's what they want.

Comment: I was thinking maybe with reflection,  but I'm not very familiar with typescript's reflection capabilities. I may have to go 100% synchronous instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a good workaround to either enforcing async calls on the consumer of the API, or preventing the if statement from evaluating true?

You can enable *strict boolean expressions* in tslint : https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/

Comment: Would this enforce the expression to wait for the async callback? I would like to keep the API returning a Promise<boolean> if I can.

Comment: It would give you a linting error since the expression is a Promise and not a boolean.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I want to do. I can code it to return a boolean, but as I mentioned in the question, I'll get `undefined` when I run it because it's relying on a Promise from the database, and I'd like to keep the methods async.

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan I'm not sure you understood the answer.  With the `strict-boolean-expressions` rule enabled, a caller that does `if(await permissions.ifAllowed(...))` will have no warnings because the await returns a boolean, while a caller that does `if(permissions.ifAllowed(...))` will get a lint error because the `if` condition is a promise and not a boolean.  I think this is exactly what you want, no?

Comment: I would prefer it be a Promise<boolean>. I could just code my side to return a boolean, but it would be 100% synchronous, and stop everything while the database is called. That's why I'd rather it stay a Promise.
Also, I think linting would not be the way to enforce it, since it's a library that would be used in projects where the lint config won't be included anyway. I will look at reflection some more to see if I can throw errors or at least warnings if there's no await on the call, but if not, I'll just accept that there's a chance it may be misused.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use external I/O, such in this case, you can't go 100% synchronous. In addition to that there i no way to enforce of using await, because omitting it's 100% valid code. This is never a problem, also for Junior node.js/JS developer, because async code is everywhere. Just document your api and it will be fine.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm going to look more into reflection and the compiled ES and see if it's detectable that way. If so, I'll just throw a console warning up. But I'm removing it from my unit test completely.

If it's no one comes up with a better solution, I'll accept this as the answer in a few weeks.